# Why are multiple conditions not being evaluated on a resource?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My CloudFormation conditions are not being evaluated correctly when I set multiple conditions on resources.

I've created a modular CodePipeline template to allow deploying with or without a database. I've placed multiple conditions on some key resources.

```
Conditions:
  HasDatabase: !Equals [ !Ref HasDatabase, true ]
  IsECS: !Equals [ !Ref IsECS, true ]

Resources:
  MyFakeBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Condition: IsECS
    Condition: HasDatabase
```

I'm expecting MyFakeBucket to be created when BOTH conditions evaluate to true, however it's created when EITHER are.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to create new conditions that were combinations on existing ones:

```
Conditions:
  HasDatabase: !Equals [ !Ref HasDatabase, true ]
  IsECS: !Equals [ !Ref IsECS, true ]
  ECSNoDB: !And
    - !Condition NoDatabase
    - !Condition IsECS
  ECSDB: !And
    - !Condition HasDatabase
    - !Condition IsECS
```

Now my resources looks like this:

```
Resources:
  MyFakeBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Condition: ECSDB
```